# Can you link Trello cards / boards?

Tags: trello-cards, trello-boards

Is it possible to allow for cards to be linked?

For example, when a feature becomes a saga and therefore the card generates its own "board" (perhaps in a different organisation—if the feature is being "outsourced") such that the smaller components of the feature appear on that.

Answer (score 30):

**Note:** This answer has been updated due to changes in Trello. Legacy information still available at the end.

## The answer

You can link to other cards in any board. Just paste the link to the card into the text...

[image: editing description]

and Trello will convert it to a nice-looking link with an icon and the card title.

[image: linked card]

When you open a card the address bar changes to a direct-link to that card, so you can copy it from there. This does mean that you have to navigate to the other card in order to get the link. The old way allowed you to start typing '#' and then choose from a list or type the number. However, it does mean that you can link to cards on other boards.

## The old way

See [Trello support](https://trello.com/c/sSldoiVf/46-deprecated-mentioning-cards-by-number-e-g-46-creates-hyperlinks) for explanation of feature deprecation: moving between boards changes card number.

Yes, you can! All you have to do is type `#xx` where `xx` is the card number - as far as I know you can do this anywhere that you input text - I have tested it in descriptions and comments.

For example you might have something like this in a card description:

```
See also:
---------

- Card #23 (Tidy shed)
- Card #4 (Clear out garage)
- Card #45 (Do that other thing)
```

The `#xx` will appear as a link to the referenced card.

Note that the card reference is working only in the same board, it is not cross-board

## Response from Trello (2016-01-27)

When the old behaviour changed I filed a bug report with Trello and got this back:

> What you discovered is actually an expected behavior at this point. We recently deprecated the number linking functionality within Trello, and at this point, unfortunately, there is no such feature available. Right now, your best bet is to use the full link to the card.
>
> We definitely understand that that's frustrating. I'm sorry that we've removed a part of Trello that was important to your use of the product. Unfortunately there were some issues with the links and they wouldn't work properly once cards have been moved to other boards. Similarly, our mobile application would only show the number and wouldn't actually build a clickable link.
>
> The best I can say is that we're working to change how we add things to Trello so we don't have to remove features in the future.

Comment: But what if my board is not English? It will appear as Card #20. Ok, You should not start a paragraph with #, because it will be interpreted as a header.

Comment: @pihentagy Spanish: Tarjeta #23 Greek: κάρτα #23 Swedish: kort #23 - you get the idea. It doesn't matter what your text says, the #23 gets automatically converted to a link.

Comment: Ok, figured out ITMT, and commented the following (maybe forgot to submit), that the only gotcha is that if the first character in the paragraph is hashmark, then it will be interpreted as header. And you cannot customize the link title.

Comment: We did this a lot, and it has stopped working :-(

Comment: Oh yeah - I just reported this as a bug here: http://help.trello.com/article/709-reporting-trello-bugs

Comment: @reinierpost ok I got to the bottom of it and updated the answer. Hope it helps. Trello support was pretty quick to respond so if you need help converting your old cards get in touch with them.

Comment: Great, thank you and thank Trello support! Too bad the feature went away, but we know where we stand now.

Comment: This is the card link explaining about the deprecation https://trello.com/c/sSldoiVf/46-deprecated-mentioning-cards-by-number-e-g-46-creates-hyperlinks

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible to link individual cards and even move a card between boards.

To find a card's link:

1. Open the card (press Enter).
2. Click the *More...* link at the bottom of the right side panel.
3. You should see a text box containing the link.

To move a card:

1. Open the card (press Enter).
2. Click the *Move...* button in the right side panel.
3. Choose your board and Click *Move*.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a small extension called [GTD: Trello Card Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtd-trello-card-links/kpbpniempdinfjfgphomcfkijinlgfgj) that allows you to put any link on the front of your Trello Cards and make it clickable. I always found it really annoying having to click on the back of cards to get to where I wanted to be!

**Features**

- Clickable Links on cards
- Multiple Links on cards
- Link to cards and create EPIC stories

[image]

**Installation Process**

1. Install extension
2. Navigate to your Trello Board
3. Create new Trello Card
4. Paste a link
5. Click the link!

---

**Resources**

- Chrome Extension: [GTD: Trello Card Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtd-trello-card-links/kpbpniempdinfjfgphomcfkijinlgfgj)
- Demo: https://trello.com/b/6DoBxhuZ/gtd-trello-card-links
- Github (opensource): https://github.com/oneezy/gtd-trello-card-links
- Patreon: https://www.patreon.com/oneezy

---

## UPDATE (01/11/2017)

I wanted to add in a few other helpful extensions I've found that might be more suitable for others use cases:

- **Extension:** [Ultimello, the features pack for Trello (Parent/Child Feature)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm?hl=en-US)
- **Extension:** [Parent/Child Management for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/parentchild-management-fo/flnpbgmiploomjgagfbcjlikpiehclld)
- **Extension:** [Nests for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nests-for-trello/eibnacdidooamhebiehhlafljlipplmd)
- **Extension:** [Next Step for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/next-step-for-trello/iajhmklhilkjgabejjemfbhmclgnmamf?hl=en)

Comment: How does it help to above question of referencing other cards? This plugin only convert URLs into clickable links

Comment: I've updated the demo to give an example of linking to the back of other cards, https://trello.com/b/6DoBxhuZ/gtd-trello-card-links

Comment: OK, this plugin is only useful for making link inside ticket names.  
And, well, putting card URL is no comparison to using #nn as it used to be.

Comment: @PaulVerest , I've updated my answer with a few other helpful extensions that might be better for the specific use case. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Trello Shortcuts Plus [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-shortcuts-plus/pfkeglfbhfmlnapfjfjfkiipclpmanim?hl=en-US) to copy the global card link with a shortcut key.

Answer (score -1):

I think [Zapier.com](http://Zapier.com) will do this.  Just do a trello to trello Zap.

Comment: No, there is no Zap to create links, as far as I can see.